# Require further reading on Custom Installers in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

Anybody got any good reading articles and tutorials on custom installers
as most on the web seem to be outdated?

The MS e-book for the 70-536 exam covers this but very lightly, as it does not cover the use of the ServiceProcessInstaller class or something like that??? I'm mentioning this here because I have seen this on quite a few exams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service installer classes are very light-weight, they just write a few registry entries.  You'll have trouble finding extensive documentation on the them, there just isn't much to write about.  Best way to learn more is to take a look at their code with Reflector.

Comment: your right dude ..... but I tght it was worth asking ... if I find anything good I will post on here.